# Treeview Virtualization and erratic scrolling

Tags: wpf, treeview, scrollbar

I have a WPF treeview with a large volume of nested data I have enabled virtualization which is working in terms of the data being loaded. But the scrolling has become unstable until the entire view has been scrolled through once then it settles down some what (still not great). I have override the ScrollViewer and I can see that the extent Height within the VirtualizingStackPanel changes erratically while scrolling.

Does anyone know of way of resolving this?

Any help is apreciated.

Relevant sections of the TreeView Xaml below:

```
        <TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding Folders.ObservableTree}" Name="FoldersTreeView"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="foldersview_treeview_folders" TabIndex="0" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem="VirtualizingStackPanel_OnCleanUpVirtualizedItem" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled ="True"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" 
                VirtualizingStackPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Item">

        <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" CanVerticallyScroll="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
        <TreeView.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <view:ScrollViewer2 Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Focusable="False" Name="TreeViewScrollViewer"  
                              CanContentScroll="True">
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </view:ScrollViewer2>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TreeView.Template>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution on this?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not, I ended up replacing the control with the DevExpress TreeListView as we have a subscription to it, this has some built in optimisations and performs well.

Answer (score 2):

Virtualization only works well if all items in the `ItemsPresenter` (and a `TreeView` is implemented as a `ItemsPresenter` with nested `ItemsPresenters`) have the same height. With a `TreeView` this is usually not the case.

The main reason for this is that because it is virtualizing, it has to estimate certain things that it would otherwise measure exactly:

The `VirtualizationStackPanel` will assume all children have the same height as currently visible children and will estimate a desired height based on this (instead of than actually measuring all children), which will be reported to the `ScrollViewer`, if the children have variable height, this estimate can be way off and will change depending on the scroll position, resulting in a continually resizing scrollbar.

Comment: I don't understand why Microsoft suggest to enable virtualization in tree views while this issue still seems to be unfixed to this day: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-a-treeview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0